# How to see Newest Questions in (alpha 0.1.50) iOS app?

Tags: support, ios-app

When I start the **(alpha 0.1.50) iOS app** on iOS 7, the **Questions** tab shows **Active** Questions (see below).

I would far prefer to see the **Newest** Questions but have not been able to find a way to configure this.

Is it possible, in the current alpha of the iOS app, to switch the Questions viewed to be sorted by Newest?

[image]

Comment: And within minutes of your post 0.1.54 has been released. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pull down to reveal the search bar. Tapping the up/down arrows on the right reveals sort options:

[image: select a sort]

From there, select whichever you want

Comment: Perfect!  Will Accept as soon as allowed (in 9 mins).

Comment: Just because my answer was first doesn't mean you need to accept it. By all means go with Martijn's, which has screenshots.

Answer (score 4):

*Scroll* a little; pull the list downwards and the search box appears. Next to the search box is a sort widget (double arrows), letting you select an alternative sort order:

[image][image]

Comment: Hand drawn circles tomorrow; this post courtesy of the iOS app.